# Array push to one of my multidimentional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array like below. I would like to push it to 0 element array.

**$csvdata is contain original array $pushHeaderSpec variable is what i want to push into original array i have also tried `array_merge` but not work as expected merge well on output only but when i print original data in csv it is not there.i m generating $csvdata array first and then append this array on last.**

```
 Array
            (
                [Ruder] => no value need on this
                [Glas] => no value need on this
                [Not] => no value need on this

            )
```

My Multidimention array look something like

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sort order
            [1] => Sku
            [2] => Title

        )
)
```

Many more element on above array so i just want to merge my first array keys to this array on first element that is 0.
I did try using below code but it doesn't give me output what i want.

```
array_push($csvdata[0],array_keys($pushHeaderSpec));
```

Output from code

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sort order
            [1] => Sku
            [2] => Title
            [3] =>array (
                [0] => Ruder
                [1] => Glas
                [2] => Not
            )

        )
)
```

Expecting Output

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Sort order
            [1] => Sku
            [2] => Title
            [3] => Ruder
            [4] => Glas
            [5] => Not


        )
)
```

Comment: OK, so what is the problem with just doing that then

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
 and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)
 and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: hahaha ```it doesn't give me the output i want!  but i won't tell you what output i want, nor will i tell you what output i'm actually getting```

Comment: You've shown two input arrays and the code you're using to try to put them together. Now you need to show _at least_ the output you're expecting, and preferably the output you're getting from your current code as well. And it would be great if you could use some smaller arrays for examples.

Comment: I have added some description above Riggs problem is that when i print array it display correctly but when i print it on csv it doesn't there.i think its due to i m generating $csvdata array first and when i try to merge on last line like `$csvdata = array_merge($csvdata[0],array_keys($pushHeaderSpec));` i can't assign it to variable $csvdata contain lot more element so hope you can understand

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you are looking for ?

```
foreach ($pushHeaderSpec as $key => $val) {
    $csvdata[0][] = $key;
}
```

Comment: @PradipGarchar Where ?

Comment: In bold letter :)

Comment: @PradipGarchar I got it, I didn't understand much the part in bold, and I didn't notice that your new array contains only keys at one time and that these keys become values afterwards. That's fixxed

Answer (score 1):

It was just

```
foreach (array_keys($pushHeaderSpec) as $key => $value) {
        array_push($csvdata[0],$value);
    }
```

Comment: That won't work with the `$pushHeaderSpec`, at least not the one you described in your question. What you want to append to `$csvdata[0]` are its keys, apparently, not its values.